# In odoo 16, ValueError: message_post does not support subtype parameter anymore. Please give a valid subtype_id or subtype_xmlid value instead

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-16

I have call `message_post` function from a wizard TransientModel. and use subtype of `hr_recruitment.mt_job_applicant_hired` and also add depended module in manifest.json but its showing error

```
ValueError: message_post does not support subtype parameter anymore. Please give a valid subtype_id or subtype_xmlid value instead.
```

```py
applicant.job_id.message_post(
                    body=_(
                        'New Employee %s Hired') % applicant.partner_name if applicant.partner_name else applicant.name,
                    subtype="hr_recruitment.mt_job_applicant_hired")
```

How to resolve it in odoo 16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you what to do. If it's not enough for clarification i advise to look into the code, where you will find the follwing.

```py
# the definition of the method with type annotation
@api.returns('mail.message', lambda value: value.id)
def message_post(self, *,
                    body='', subject=None, message_type='notification',
                    email_from=None, author_id=None, parent_id=False,
                    subtype_xmlid=None, subtype_id=False, partner_ids=None,
                    attachments=None, attachment_ids=None,
                    **kwargs):
```

First thing you will see: there is no `subtype` anymore. Instead Odoo developers have added a check on `kwargs` which will give you the error message:

```py
if 'subtype' in kwargs:
    raise ValueError(_("message_post does not support subtype parameter anymore. Please give a valid subtype_id or subtype_xmlid value instead."))
```

Instead of `subtype` you have `subtype_id` or `subtype_xmlid` as new parameters. So your code have to be changed to:

```py
applicant.job_id.message_post(
    body=_(
        'New Employee %s Hired') % applicant.partner_name if applicant.partner_name else applicant.name,
    subtype_xmlid="hr_recruitment.mt_job_applicant_hired"
)
```